# how to skip first n element from collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to skip, some element from collection

```
$post_one = Post_one::all();
$post_two = Post_two::all();
$posts = collect();
if($post_one){
    foreach($post_one as $post){
        $posts->push($post);
    }
}
if($post_two){
    foreach($post_two as $post){
       $posts->push($post);
    }
}
//now i want to skip n=3, element form the collection of posts
$posts = $posts->sortBy('created_at')-<skip(3)->take(3);//does not work
```

error::Method skip does not exist.

Comment: Do you want to take 3 as well after skipping 3?

Comment: did you find other means to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To combine both records you can use [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) method with [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-flatten), i,e

```
$posts = $post_one->flatten(1)->merge($post_two)->sortBy('created_at');
```

Then you use [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) to get the right result:

```
$filtered = $posts->filter(function ($post, $key) {
    return $key > 2;
});
```

This skips the first 3 since the key starts from 0...n.

Or you can just [slice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-slice) the collection:

```
$nextthree = $posts->slice(3, 3);
```

This skips 3 and takes the next 3 from the collection. You can access the original collections `$posts`.

At this point the index of the collection is preserved, but to reset it to start from 0...n just use `values()` method i.e:

```
$nextthree = $posts->slice(3, 3)->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `forPage()` method.
Like this:

`$posts = $posts->forPage($currentPage, $perPage);`

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-forpage)